# No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/react-native`

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I got an error:

```
 No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/react-native`
```

And this is my Podfile:

```
    target 'RNNativeOrientationInteractor' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!


  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [upgrade tool report](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.60.6&to=0.61.4), If your ReactNative Version between `0.60.6 - 0.61.1`. `React-Core.podspec` was moved from

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

to

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
```

But for previous versions, Change your `React-Core` path in `Podfile` to

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

In order to confirm that, Check path `../node_modules/react-native/React/React-Core.podspec` is really exists relative to Podfile.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.