# No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/React`

Tags: react-native, podfile

First its not duplicated. Because i have different issue. I upgraded my react Native version to '0.62.2' (I wish I hadn't upgraded). I'm dealing with a lot of problems right now.This is my problem now  No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/React` and I couldn't solve it

It is seen that there is always wrong path in similar problems. But even though I wrote the correct path, it gives an error. Also when I look at '../node_modules/react-native' I can't see the React-Core file here
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I found similar problems and solutions. as in the examples below

1. [No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/react-native/React`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588687/no-podspec-found-for-react-core-in-node-modules-react-native-react)
2. [No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/react-native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300493/no-podspec-found-for-react-core-in-node-modules-react-native)

> pod install
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
>
> [!] No podspec found for `React-Core` in `../node_modules/React`

**Podfile**

````
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'DGFonder' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  p
end

swift4 = ['Charts']

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

    targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)
      
    if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
      target.remove_from_project
    end

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if swift4.include?(target.name)
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end
```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNLjD.png
````

Answer (score 0):

React is now part of react-native in node_modules. So, you need to update your `React-Core` pod as:

```
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

Notice `react-native` in path specified.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue this is because of node_modules
just do following steps

1. remove all node_modules
2. run npm i and check if there is any Vulnerabilities then perform npm audit fix
3. go to ios folder
4. run pod install
5. and it will work

Answer (score 0):

i also face the same issue,

solution:-

1. you have updated git clone package
2. npm install
   3.open path nodemodules/rn-fetch-blob
3. open rn-fetch-blob.podspec file
4. change React/native to React-native
5. cd ios && pod install
   7.for android open android studio and then open your project android folder in android studio
   8.for ios first go to ios folder of your project and then open RECA.xcworkspace
   9.Run build in Xcode
6. Thanks